# How do I make a set of images/links more responsive for a mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, styles

I am trying to make my set of portfolio images more responsive when it gets below about 730px and again at 560px. I may have dug myself a hole as I coded this page a ways back before I was a little better at this stuff. Anyway, any style suggestions/coding suggestions would be great. I have some open media queries at the bottom that target the images themselves. I really appreciate any help!

```
#portfolio {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 80px;
text-align: center;
}
#portfolio .port-entry {
border-radius: 8px;
width: 32%;
height: 32%;
display: inline-block; 
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
}

.description {
padding-top: 35px;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
transition: all .3s ease;
color: white;
border-radius: 8px;  
}

.description:hover {
 opacity: .9;
 height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/MindfulBell/pen/NxGNWN

Comment: It's always best to code from mobile up to desktop, put you desktop stuff into @media min-width, also putting a min-width on your image containers might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back but with my navbar being too large when the screen was smaller. You might be able to adapt my solution to fit yours. you are going to have to write three css sets for the three different sizes. You may want to play around with the code, pay attention to my comments and find how it works for you. Hope this helps.

then you will have:

```
    /*--Set 1: >760px high--*/
    #portfolio {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #portfolio .port-entry {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 32%;
    display: inline-block; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
    }

    .description {
    padding-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    }

    .description:hover {
     opacity: .9;
     height: 100%;
    }
    /*--Set 2: 561-730px high (or did you want wide? if so just change "height" to "width".--*/
    @media all and (max-height: 730px){
    #portfolio {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #portfolio .port-entry {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 32%;
    display: inline-block; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
    }

    .description {
    padding-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    }

    .description:hover {
     opacity: .9;
     height: 100%;
    }
    }
   /*--Set 3: 0-560px high (or did you want wide? if so just change "height" to "width".--*/
    @media all and (max-height: 560px){
    #portfolio {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #portfolio .port-entry {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 32%;
    display: inline-block; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
    }

    .description {
    padding-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    }

    .description:hover {
     opacity: .9;
     height: 100%;
    }
    }
    /*--Set 3: 0-560px high (or did you want wide? if so just change "height" to "width".--*/
    @media all and (min-height: 1px){
    #portfolio {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #portfolio .port-entry {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 32%;
    display: inline-block; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px black;
    }

    .description {
    padding-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;  
    }

    .description:hover {
     opacity: .9;
     height: 100%;
    }
    }
```